# EF4: For a new app, is it better to generate db scripts for an empty db, or generate class from an db with tables in already in place?

Tags: entity-framework

For my first app I created the db and the tables it used. I was not impressed that I had to use buddy classes for validation, but at least I know what I am doing now.
For my next app, is it worth learning instead how to create db scripts to populate an empty db, and do it that way round? I suspect it is, but let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it quicker to design using the EF Designer and then generate the database from that.  It's less key strokes overall.  Sometimes I'll then make changes in the database and bring them back into the model, but for that first pass, EF designer works great.